# Insert two columns from two different tables into another table in SQL

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have been searching for a solution to my problem for quite a bit, but couldn't find anywhere. 
Here is my problem: I have two columns from two different tables and want to insert them into another table which is empty. I have tried to run this query but it doesn't work and I don't even know why:

```
SELECT a.column, c.column 
FROM FirstTable.column a, SecondTable.column c
left outer join ThirdTable.column b on a.column = b.column
left outer join ThirdTable.column b on c.column = b.column
```

After running this, I receive the following message:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "a.column" could not be bound.
Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The correlation name 'b' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.
```

I would also like to add that a.column has 1143 rows, and c.column has 2057 rows. Both are PK for their respective tables.

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Please rewite the query with the real column and table names. 
You can only use the alias 'b' once in your FROM clause. Here you are using it twice

Answer (score 3):

Try reframing your query as

```
SELECT a.column, c.column 
FROM Table a left outer join Table b on a.column = b.column 
left outer join Table c on c.column = b.column
```

Would have been better if you provided exact query, but the problem is most likely with the joins.

Comment: And yes... "Table a" and "Table b" mean the table names instead of the keyword Table as pointed out by michael

Comment: Your query returns me two columns - that's great! However, all rows in c.column are NULL. Thanks. The same happens to D Stanley's query below

Comment: Need to look at the data to see why the query is behaving this way

Answer (score 1):

I used a set of temp table variables to display the concept, but it should be easily translated to actual tables.

```
DECLARE @tabl1 TABLE (col1 int DEFAULT 1)
    INSERT INTO @tabl1 VALUES (1)

DECLARE @tabl2 TABLE (col2 int DEFAULT 2)
    INSERT INTO @tabl2 VALUES (2)

DECLARE @tabl3 TABLE (col1 int, col2 int)

-- This should be what you need.

INSERT INTO @tabl3
SELECT a.col1
     , b.col2
FROM @tabl1 a, @tabl2 b

SELECT * FROM @tabl3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing a cartesian join, you've got a mixture of explicit and implicit syntax.  I would pick one or the other (being partial to explicit syntax myself):

```
SELECT a.column, c.column 
FROM Table a
left outer join Table b on a.column = b.column
left outer join Table c on b.column = c.column
```

or whatever works for your structure.

Comment: It gives me the same result as Pankaj's query - two columns (good for the start) but c.columns is all NULL but it shouldn't be. What do you mean by explicit and implicit syntax here?

Comment: Implicit syntax is `SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.key = b.key`.  Explicit is `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.key = b.key`

Comment: If the second column is all null then there are no records that match the join criteria from either A to B or B to C.

Comment: They are kind of related (not straigthforward, however) by some columns in other tables

Comment: That doesn't help me - you need to figure out the proper join to relate the tables.